# Add New Folder icon to blue/green bar (Command Bar) in Vista Explorer

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

First of all, what is that blue/green bar in Vista called?  The one with Organize, Views and a whole bunch of useless icons. (**Update** this is the Command Bar.)

How do I add a Create New Folder icon to that bar?  In general, can I play with it?

Comment: Actually would have been a nice question if you left it in the original state. Would help others who might not know it's called the command bar.

Comment: +1 Agreed, no need to remove the first quesition.

Comment: Now that is a rollback worth an upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The bar is called the command bar.

   **[Quote Diago](https://superuser.com/questions/17216/add-new-folder-icon-to-blue-green-bar-in-vista-explorer/17217#17217)**:

   > [...] The bar itself is actually a replacement for the standard toolbar and is a hybrid between a toolbar and a ribbon similar to the one's found in Office 2007 and upwards. It adapts itself according to the available features dependent on where you are inside the navigation system. [...]
2. You can add buttons to it, but [apparently not the `New Folder`](http://www.aeroxp.org/2008/06/custom-explorer-buttons/) button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bar itself is actually a replacement for the standard toolbar and is a hybrid between a toolbar and a ribbon similar to the one's found in Office 2007 and upwards. It adapts itself according to the available features dependent on where you are inside the navigation system.

For example. New Folder will appear whenever you navigate a drive you have read/write rights on, however when looking at the Computer screen where it lists all available and attached drives, it will change to show computer management tasks like Control Panel and Map Network Drive.

As far as I am aware there is no way to change what it displays due to it's adaptive nature.